# How to apply validation on multiple check boxes while i have checkboxes in for loop

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to apply validation on multiple check boxes but question is how to do it?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","thisis");
mysql_select_db("my_database");

if(isset($_GET["q"]))
{
$my_q = $_GET['q'];
$q="select * from subjects where subj_code='$my_q'";
$rs=mysql_query($q);

    for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($rs);$i++)
    {
        $rd=mysql_fetch_object($rs);

?>

        <input type="checkbox" name="subj[]" value="<?php echo $rd->subj_name; ?>" /><?php echo $rd->subj_name; ?>
        <br />
<?php
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: What do you want to validate? When do you want to validate it? What have you tried?

Comment: Just to note that `mysql_fetch_object` has been deprecated as of 5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
obj = document.form1.elements("subj[]");
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].checked) {
        alert("Your text");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please give me some other way.It is not working i tried it in this way php code  <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","mydata");
  mysql_select_db("student_management");
 
 if(isset($_GET["q"]))
 {
 $my_q = $_GET['q'];
 $q="select * from subjects where subj_code='$my_q'";
 $rs=mysql_query($q);
 ?>

   <?php
   for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($rs);$i++)
  {
   $rd=mysql_fetch_object($rs);
   ?>
            
   <input type="checkbox" name="subj[]" onclick="myvalid()" value="<?php echo $rd->subj_name; ?>"  /><?php echo $rd->subj_name; ?>
            <br />
<?php
  }
  
 }
?>

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if($('input[name="sub[]"]:checked').length == 0) {
   alert('No checkbox is checked');
   return false;
}
```